# Calculation of the hours of the current week from Monday to Sunday

Tags: excel

This is my Excel spreadsheet

```
17.03.2021 1 h
19.03.2021 2 h
22.03.2021 3 h
25.03.2021 8 h
29.03.2021 4 h
```

And I would like to calculate always how much hour I get per week. The week starts from Monday to Sunday. It should always be taken into account the current week. Say it should calculate me only the week from 22.03.2021 to 28.03.2021. The result should be 11 hours.

I managed to add all times together, but how do I take into account which week it is and how do I take the current week out of the block considering that the week goes from Monday to Sunday?

Comment: Use countif() with date limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Sum if same week]

If these are columns A-D, then the formula for col C is "=WEEKNUM(A2,1)", and the formula for col D is "=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5,$C$2:$C$5,C2)".

You could do this with a single function, but it's hopefully more readable this way.

Oh, and if your data covers more than a single year, then you'd need a 'Year' column, and you'd have to add that as a criteria to the 'SUMIFS'.